# What is the Numpy slicing notation in this code?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

```py
# split into inputs and outputs

X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]

print(X.shape, y.shape)
```

Can someone explain the second line of code with reference to specific documentation? I know its slicing but the I couldn't find any reference for the notation ":-1" anywhere. Please give the specific documentation portion.

Thank you

It results in slicing, most probably using `numpy` and it is being done on a data of shape `(610, 14)`

Comment: In any slicing reference, -n refers to the nth last term. So -1 is the last term, -2 is second last term and so on

Comment: This is typical  ML data.  The last column is the labels,`y` 1d.  The rest is the 2d data, `X`, samples by features (all columns except the last)

Comment: Standard python slice notation, `start:stop:step`; `-n` counts from end.  So `:-1` is 'all but last'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs:

## [Indexing on `ndarrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

> `ndarrays` can be indexed using the standard Python `x[obj]` syntax, where *x* is the *array* and *obj* the selection. There are different kinds of indexing available depending on *obj*: basic indexing, advanced indexing and field access.

## 1D array

Slicing a 1-dimensional array is much like slicing a list

```py
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)
array_1d = np.random.random((5,))

print(len(array_1d.shape))
```

```
1
```

**NOTE:** The `len` of the array *shape* tells you the number of dimensions.

We can use standard python list slicing on the 1D array.

```py
# get the last element
print(array_1d[-1])
```

```
0.4236547993389047
```

```py
# get everything up to but excluding the last element
print(array_1d[:-1])
```

```
[0.5488135  0.71518937 0.60276338 0.54488318]
```

## 2D array

```py
array_2d = np.random.random((5, 1))

print(len(array_2d.shape))
```

```
2
```

Think of a 2-dimensional array like a data frame. It has rows (the 0th axis) and columns (the 1st axis). `numpy` grants us the ability to slice these axes independently by separating them with a comma (`,`).

```py
# the 0th row and all columns
# the 0th row and all columns
print(array_2d[0, :])
```

```
[0.79172504]
```

```py
# the 1st row and everything after + all columns
print(array_2d[1:, :])
```

```
[[0.52889492]
 [0.56804456]
 [0.92559664]
 [0.07103606]]
```

```py
# the 1st through second to last row + the last column
print(array_2d[1:-1, -1])
```

```
[0.52889492 0.56804456 0.92559664]
```

## Your Example

```py
# split into inputs and outputs

X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]

print(X.shape, y.shape)
```

Note that `data.shape` is `>= 2` (otherwise you'd get an `IndexError`).

This means `data[:, :-1]` is keeping all "rows" and slicing up to, but not including, the last "column". Likewise, `data[:, -1]` is keeping all "rows" and selecting *only* the last "column".

It's important to know that when you slice an `ndarray` using a colon (`:`), you will get an array with the same dimensions.

```py
print(len(array_2d[1:, :-1].shape))  # 2
```

But if you "select" a specific index (i.e. don't use a colon), you *may* reduce the dimensions.

```py
print(len(array_2d[1, :-1].shape))  # 1, because I selected a single index value on the 0th axis

print(len(array_2d[1, -1].shape))  # 0, because I selected a single index value on both the 0th and 1st axes
```

You can, however, select a *`list` of indices* on either axis (assuming they exist).

```py
print(len(array_2d[[1], [-1]].shape))  # 1

print(len(array_2d[[1, 3], :].shape))  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This slicing notation is explained here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

-1 means last element, -2 - second from last, etc. For example, if there are 8 elements in a list, -1 is equivalent to 7 (not 8 because indexing starts from 0)

Keep in mind that "normal"  python slicing for nested lists looks like `[1:3][5:7]`, while numpy arrays also have a slightly different syntax (`[8:10, 12:14]`) that lets you slice multidimensional arrays. However, -1 always means the same thing. Here is the numpy documentation for slicing https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html